# Advanced custom fields displaying incorrectly on category pages. How do i limit to my taxonomy page only?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I added the code below to my archive page.

```
 <?php  
  $taxonomy = get_query_var('taxonomy');
  $termId = get_queried_object()->term_id;
  the_field('embed', $taxonomy . '_' . $termId);
  the_field('download_output', $taxonomy . '_' . $termId);
  echo get_field('embed', $term);
  echo get_field('download_output', $term);
  ?>
```

The archive page include taxonomy pages and category pages. The above code is displaying incorrectly on category pages. How do i limit the code above to only display on the taxonmy term "downloads"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve but you can create taxonomy-downloads.php file in your theme and it will display only for this taxonomy